# About Raspberry Pi mote in Contiki OS

Tags: sensor

I have started exploring Contiki OS. I have a tool named COOJA simulator in it to simulate sensor networks (Here, the sensor node is called "mote"). In this simulator where in we have many types of motes like sky mote, z1 mote, wismote etc but I have not found a Raspberry Pi there.

I have a doubt like if we connect a raspberry pi with a sensor is it becomes a mote? Or do we have to use the Pi-mote module in it ([Pi-mote Control starter kit with 2 sockets](https://energenie4u.co.uk/index.phpcatalogue/product/ENER002-2PI)).

Can we conclude if Raspberry + Sensor = Pi-mote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contiki OS is an OS for resource constrained platforms (mostly 8 and 16 bit Micro-controller based) where you can't run a full fledge traditional OS. It's similar to other such OSes like RIOT OS and TinyOS.

RPi falls in a single board computer category where you can run full fledge OS with all the traditional stacks.

As far as I know, Contiki doesn't support RPi and hence COOJA also doesn't have RPi in its mote list.

> I have a doubt like if we connect a raspberry pi with a sensor is it
>   becomes a mote?

Technically, yes. Since by definition, a mote in sensor networks is a system which is connected to network and sends sensor data over network.

The pi-mote module in question is an RF module, and is not actually a mote as you imagine in sensor networks.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but with the constrain of contiki os to Raspberry pi, I have my doubts. However, you can try Ubuntu Raspberry mate, perhaps you can resolve this issue via it https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/.